# c# Data table not loading data

Tags: c#, ado

I have a method in a c# console app that passes a string of a stored procedure name and returns a datatable.

```
public DataTable Table(int val,string ProcedureName)
{
    string Pk = "@" + ProcedureName + "Id";
    var command = GetCommand(ProcedureName);
    command.Parameters[Pk].Value = val;
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;         
    adapter.Fill(table);
    return table;
}
```

Here is the code for the GetCommand helper method

```
internal SqlCommand GetCommand(string ProcedureName)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()
    {
        Connection = BuildingSecurityContext(),
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        CommandText = ProcedureName
    };

    _BuildingSecurityContext.Open();
    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
    _BuildingSecurityContext.Close();
    return cmd;
}
```

Here is the method that prints the results to the console.

```
static void ReadResults(DataTable table)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{table.Rows[i].Field<int>(0)}{table.Rows[i].Field<string>(1)}{table.Rows[i].Field<string>(2)}");
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting a error that it can't find column 1. (It seems to me that the command is not filling the datatable).

Can someone point me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Would it be cleaner to debug if you placed the values from the table in variables? Then you can debug and will be able to see the values on execution step thru code and you'll have intellisense to help. First thing I'd do is confirm that table.rows.count > 0 and count is accurate and your sproc is returning what it should.

Answer (score 1):

parameters start with @ but most procedures don't -- are you sure you want to prepend an @ sign?

also this line makes no sense

```
 command.Parameters[Pk].Value = val;
```